# Closest snapping in object mode does not use closest vertex when multiple objects are selected

Tags: snapping

The [snapping page in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html#snap-with) says that the snap with closest option should "move the closest point of the selection to the target". That only works when a single object is selected though, making it fairly useless since you can also easily work in edit mode in that case.

Take a look at this: https://youtu.be/0uuCatZnCzk

I want to snap the door to the outcropping in the wall, but I don't want to use the origin of the parent which is used as the hinge position. Instead I want use the closest vertex from the door frame which is a child of the hinge. That works fine if only the door frame object is selected, but as soon as the parent object is part of the selection it will always use its origin no matter what, even though it is clearly much further away from the vertex I'm using as the snapping target and the frame is the active object, not the parent.

Situations like this come up all the time, do I seriously have to unparent and move the child object I want to use for the snapping first and then move the parent to match its position afterwards and then reparent the child?